# What is the meaning of print()[] in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

While browsing codegolf, I found [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12007/8558) :

```py
g=input();print("Approved","Summer School","Failed")[(g<7)+(g<3)]
```

I don't understand what the [] means after print()... Any clarification ?

Comment: Think `print`, `("Approved","Summer School","Failed")[(g<7)+(g<3)]` separately, then you will get it.   It's Tuple and indexing.

Comment: FWIW, whoever thought that `(...)[(g<7)+(g<3)]` was a good idea is crazy!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's code golf; *crazy* is the name of the game!

Comment: @arshajii Ah, code golf, in that case it needs to be further obfuscated, this was far too easy to decode!!

Comment: Probably worth noting for future generations that this would not work in Python 3, since `print` was changed to use standard function syntax.

Comment: @sr2222 Yup, already done ......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> print("Approved","Summer School","Failed")[0]
Approved
>>> print("Approved","Summer School","Failed")[1]
Summer School
>>> print("Approved","Summer School","Failed")[2]
Failed
```

See the pattern? It's just simple indexing.

By the way we always know `(g<7)+(g<3)` will be `>= 0` (`False + False`) and `<= 2` (`True + True`).

Recall that `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and that `True == 1` and `False == 0` (which is why we can add `bool`s, as is done above).

Finally, it goes without saying that this confusion could have easily been avoided with an extra set of parenthesis:

```
print(("Approved","Summer School","Failed")[(g<7)+(g<3)])
```

Comment: You may want to make it explicit that `True` and `False` are booleans, and that `bool` is a subclass of `int` in Python, and thus `True` == 1 and `False` == 0...

Answer (score 2):

It's just tuple indexing. No different from this:

```
x = (1, 2, 3)[1]
```

which assigns `2` to `x`.

In your more complex variant, an element of the tuple is selected and then passed to `print`.

The confusion is that the code makes it look like you are calling a function named `print`. This confusion was removed in Python 3 by dint of `print` being turned into a function. The code in your question does something utterly different in Python 3.

Comment: *does something utterly different in Python 3*: yeah, fail miserably with `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Please don't tell me you had to execute that to find out what would happen .........  I expect more from the ninja......   ;-)

Comment: Nope. It's worse than that. I know the exceptions by heart.. **or** I just entered `None[0]` into an open Python prompt to remind me. That `print()` returns `None` is common knowledge, not?

Comment: Common knowledge or informed guess, the end result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

`print(x,y,...)[i]` should be parsed as `print (x,y)[i]`. Its just print followed by `tuple`.